# How to play audio onClick in React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

The HTML:

```
             <div id="page">
                    <div id="audio-container">
                        <div id="audio-names">
                            <ul>
                                <li onClick={() => this.playAudio(0)}>
                                    Audio 1
                                </li>
                                <li onClick={() => this.playAudio(1)}>
                                    Audio 2
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

The onClick:

```
playTrack(index) {
    switch (index) {
        case 0:
            // Logic to play audio 0
        case 1:
            // Logic to play audio 1
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

I've tried a couple ways but they lead to errors that I can't seem to decipher (for example, just trying this.audio.play() gives a "DOMException: The element has no supported sources." in my console log).

Edit:

```
            var playPromise = this.audio0.play();
            if (playPromise !== undefined) {
                playPromise.then(function () {
                    // I left this block empty
                }).catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error)
                });
            }
```

this.audio0 and this.audio1 is defined in my constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.audio0 = new Audio('../resources/songs/audio0.mp3');
    this.audio1 = new Audio('../resources/songs/audio1.mp3');
}
```

Comment: That's commented out, as in that is where I want to place the logic to play the audio. It isn't actual code

Comment: Actually I'm not quite sure what you're asking - if you mean where am I defining "audio" when I tried this.audio.play(), I'm defining audio inside my constructor.

Comment: I edited the OP to include how I was calling this.audio0.play and how I was defining this.audio0 and this.audio1

Comment: It may be because the requested endpoint doesn't return the audio file you were expecting (maybe it's giving a 404 page instead, or something). I'd check your network tab, verify that the `../resources/songs/audio0.mp3` path is reaching what you're intending. Make sure the response is black (worked) rather than red (failed)

Comment: The path I'm trying is the same one I use for how I actually import my resources. So it works for say "import image1 from "../resources/images/image1.png", if I'm trying to import an image from my resources folder. I'm not sure if the path to play an audio file would look different?

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure they will look different. Again, check your network tab, it's probably failing. The build folder is probably not the exact same as the output folder on the website. One option is to put the audio files into some public folder on the site and then request from there, eg so that you can do `example.com/songs/audio1.mp3` in the address bar - if that succeeds, you'll know you can use `new Audio` to reference the file

Comment: There may be another way to import the resources statically via webpack (or however you're bundling), but that's more complicated and would increase bundle size.

Comment: Ah ok thanks finally figured it out

Comment: @ihatestackoverflowsomuch2 So what was the solution?